# Group dataframe based on a column in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called table4 with many columns including the diff_charge column. i need to group the column based on diff_charge and then find sum of diff_charge values that are greater than 0

link to excel file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uUBwOXjoP7_zwYdDkBNT01YSEb9JnKlr/edit?usp=drive_link&ouid=106245133256779335502&rtpof=true&sd=true

[dataframe image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Bt4c.png)

Comment: Download the dataset and put it in your working directory.

Comment: Are you running this in Kaggle  or is it your local R installation?  In Kaggle, linked datasets are available through `../input/`, i.e.  `read.csv("../input/hotel-booking/hotel_booking.csv")`  .

Comment: still havent found the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

your question is unclear, what do you mean, groupby diff_charge column and find sum of diff charge greater than 0, if you group by diffcharge column, you can not make any change to grouped column, if you only want to get only two numbers lets say, sum of diff charge greater than 0, and sum of diff charge less than 0, then use following code:

```
table4 %>% 
  mutate(direction = case_when(
    diff_charge >= 0 ~ "positive",
    diff_charge < 0 ~ "negative"
  )) %>% 
  group_by(direction) %>% 
  summarize(summ = sum(diff_charge)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```